# Set an image as transparent background watermark

Tags: beamer

I'm realizing my first presentation in beamer.
I'm thinking about setting an image (the logo of my institute) as a background for all the frames.
The image should be quite transparent, because there will be a text above it, and be placed in the center of the frame, full screen.
Is it possible? How?

Comment: If text is *above* it, it shouldn't matter whether the image is tranparent.

Comment: @Jubobs: Depends on the image. (I personally hate such background images. I will never understand why people want to make reading more difficult.)

Comment: I use something similar for some presentations but I only use it on the titlepage - not on pages where people need to pay attention to the content as such. Also, in my experience, the image needs to be much more transparent than a preview on your machine suggests as the background image can appear more opaque when projected using the LCD beamer. Unless you can test on the equipment you'll be using before hand, be prepared for the possibility that pages using the background will be entirely illegible. Even if you can test on the same equipment, I'd still only use it on the titlepage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a sample using `tikz` of course.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\node[opacity=0.4]at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo}};}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \kant[1]
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}
    \kant[2]
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To make it full screen (which I wouldn't) adjust the width and height in `\includegraphics`